# PHP Array Duplicate Value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => FooBar
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => BarFoo
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => FooFoo
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => FooFoo
            )

    )
```

)

I basically want to be able to look at [2] and [3] and be able to merge those two together since their values are the same. Basically I just don't want to double count. Is there a simple way of doing this while looping through?

Comment: Is this structure always the same? [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Foo] => FooBar
            )

    )

Comment: Yes, obviously with different values, but yes same structure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$unique_array = array_map("unserialize",
      array_unique(array_map("serialize", $your_array)));
```